# How do I get key name from $key in foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){

Tags: php, post

I have dynamic field names that are being posted to my form processor. The names are formatted like `editnote|9`. `|9` being the ID of the note to edit. If I use this code:

```
foreach($_POST as $key) {

    $editcheck = explode('|', $key);

    if($editcheck[0] == 'editnote') {
        echo $editcheck[1];
    }
}
```

I can properly get the ID of 9, but I cannot get the value. I have tried:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

    $editcheck = explode('|', $key);

    if($editcheck[0] == 'editnote') {
        $clsCNA->updatenote($editcheck[1], $_POST[$key]);
    }
}
```

But with this code, I can only get the value and not the key name to get the note ID I want to edit.

So basically, I want `foreach($_POST as $key => $value)` to somehow allow me to get the name of `$key` so I can explode it to get the ID number.

Any ideas?

I am trying to send to my class like this:

```
$clsCNA->updatenote(ID From key name, Value of key)
```

Comment: I think you might have to add some extra data. What exactly is the value you're trying to pass to your function? A value from $_REQUEST, where `editnote|9` is the key?

Comment: If you use the `$key=>$value` syntax of foreach, then you should have the value already in the variable named so appropriately `$value` – so why would you want to fish it out of `$_POST` again …?

Comment: On the HTML side the form will send as POST "editnote|9" and the value will be whatever the user enters in the form.

Comment: If i am doing key=>$value I cannot get the name of the key using $key. I just want to know what the key is named. Doing key=>$value I already have the value but no key name. The ID of the note to edit is stored in that key name.

Comment: You just need to use the first loop, then. The contents is in `$_POST[$key]`, surely?

Comment: _“If i am doing key=>$value I cannot get the name of the key using $key.”_ – what does that mean? What does `var_dump($key)` inside the foreach loop give you …?

Comment: $_POST[$key] was returning "Value" instead of the text user enters when doing it in the first loop.

Comment: CBroe, what I mean is that I want the name of the key when doing $key=>$value . For instance, if the form had a textbox for your name and <input name="randominputname"> I would want $key to return "randominputname"

Comment: Stop letting us guess, `var_dump($_POST)` and show us what data you're actually working with! If `foreach($_POST as $key)` works for you to get the "key", then there is no value! `$key` is the value.

Comment: Sorry deceze, I didn't think about doing that. Here is the full var_dump for $_POST :

Key: value; Value: Test modification  
Key: id; Value: editnote|8 


Not sure why its getting multiple keys... the html field name is editnote|8 and the value should be "Test modification" but it doesnt look like its coming in that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use this code:

```
foreach($_POST as $key) {

    $editcheck = explode('|', $key);

    if($editcheck[0] == 'editnote') {
        echo $editcheck[1];
    }
}
```

> I can properly get the ID of 9...

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
```

> CUT ...

As [PHP's foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop using one variable will only take the values of the array. The exact names chosen does not determine what what goes into the variables. Similarly found by method calls.
This will be put the **Value** into the `$key` variable.

In the second example you are using the `$key => $value` syntax. Here the loop puts the **Key** into the `$key` variable and the **Value** into the `$value` variable.

What this means is that your `$key` variable is not the same in both examples. In one it holds the **Values** of the array in the other it holds the **Keys**.